# Deleted group is rendrered after saving the layer to JSON

Tags: json, kineticjs

I have a Kinetic.Group which contains text and shapes, and is drawn on a layer. When I remove it, along with its children :

```
grp.destroyChildren();
grp.destroy();
layer.draw();
stage.add(layer);
```

and save the layer to JSON :

```
var json = layer.toJSON();
console.log(json);
```

I get an empty group in the console, the text and shapes are in fact deleted from the layer. I tried `.remove()` and still get the same result. What should I write to get a JSON variable that contains only the description of the empty layer?

---

**BIG EDIT**

The problem does even not exist. It was an extra call of `layer.add(group);` that I was calling before thinking about adding the functionality of saving to JSON. Here's a good fiddle that illustrates the logic: http://jsfiddle.net/s695J/

Comment: Can you provide demo? I don't have empty group in this demo: http://jsbin.com/xored/1/edit

Comment: Oh thanks :) you helped me without knowing. It was an extra `layer.add(group);`